# Generics: Clear slice of array efficiently (no-op for primitives)

Tags: arrays, go

I have a generic array inside a `struct` that is kept around:

```golang
type S[T any] struct { arr [42]T }
var  sInt S[int]
var  sStr S[string]
```

Currently, I use the following `clear` function to clear slices of this array after I don't need them anymore to prevent memleaks:

```golang
func clear[T any](slice []T) {
    var nilT T
    for i := range slice {
        slice[i] = nilT
    }
}
```

which I then use as follows:

```
clear(sInt.arr[3:]) // this should be a no-op
clear(sStr.arr[3:]) // this needs to clear
```

I would like to make `clear` a no-op if `T` is a primitive type; I don't mind outdated garbage values, I merely want to prevent memleaks if `T` is a reference type. Is this possible in Go *without* changing the underlying generic array to a slice?

(Context: This is for a B-Tree implementation; to keep the overhead low when using small orders - and since the size is known at compile time - I use arrays instead of slices inside my `struct`s; I don't need the pointer, capacity, length for both the values and children - I only need one small length field per node)

Comment: Use `reflect` to determine whether you want `clear` to do its thing or do nothing. Note that `sInt[3:]` and `sStr[3:]` are not valid expressions given that both `sInt` and `sStr` are of type _struct_. Structs do not support indexing/slicing expressions.

Comment: @mkopriva right, fixed, meant `sInt.arr[3:]` and `sStr.arr[3:]` of course. Would reflection help performance for small slices (< 8 elements); would it be faster than just zeroing them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no support to detect "reference" types. If you really need this, you could use type assertion (type switch) or reflection to detect if you need to perform the clear operation.

But please note that Go 1.21 added a builtin [`clear()`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Clear) function which likely uses highly optimized code to zero a slice for example. I also believe it zeros an array of size 42 faster than you could use reflection to detect clear-able types.

So to clear an array of type `arr [42]T`, just do:

```
clear(arr[:])
```

Comment: Will definitely consider `clear`; how would I support older Go versions though? I was hoping there would be a way to have the clearing be optimized out entirely at compile time for primitives (since I'm doing it just for GC purposes and don't care about the values), but that doesn't seem to be possible with how Go generics are implemented.

Comment: @Luatic If you want to make it work with older Go versions, you could create a file defining the `clear()` function, and use build constraints to only compile that file if go version is 
prior to go 1.21.

Comment: Note that Go 1.21's `clear` builtin function can do things no older version of Go can do out of the box, namely deleting keys that are not reflexive for equality (e.g. `NaN`).